# creating a server project in vb6 and ms-access

Tags: ms-access, vb6

i am making a project in visual basic 6 and ms-access. Its about college management system
and is a server based application. Clients can access the system in the server. But the main problem is how can i make my client use the access file located in the server computer.?? if my database file is already opened in the server computer then my clients cannot access the file in the server. Is there any another way to resolve the problem?

How can i make a database file in access so that all my clients can use it simultaneously?
Please help...

Comment: you mean without killing yourself in the process? ;)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'll find your answer [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289681).
Quoting from the MSDN article:

> To prevent this behavior, you must
>   make sure that all users who open the
>   database have read, write, and create
>   rights for the folder in which the
>   database is located.
>
> Additionally, if you are using a
>   security-enhanced Access database, you
>   must make sure that the users who open
>   the database also have Read permission
>   and Write permission on the folder
>   that contains the workgroup
>   information (.mdw) file.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason why clients on other computers can't open the same access database at the same time.  What makes you think they can't?  Can you provide more details on the problem?

That said are really sure you want be using MS Access as the DB?  Why not simply use SQL Server 2008 Express?  You can use either the SQL 2008 management tools to administer this DB or you can use MS Access connected to the SQL 2008 Express engine.  This approach will definitely be considerable more stable and significantly faster.

**Edit**:

To answer your question more specifically it is possible to open an Access database exclusively which would result in your problem.  Are you using ADO?  What is your connection string?

Comment: I have to agree, there is no reason to use Access as the DBMS on a multi user system. I dropped MS Access when SQL 2005 express became available and I have never regretted that.
BTW why VB6 when Microsoft stopped support for that product in March last year?

Comment: Actually dont have much idea about microsoft sql server so asked .. and btw i have tried to access the same database file with my client when it is already opened by my server, It says "The file is already in use'.

Comment: And i have been told by my college to work on vb6 and ms access :(

Comment: Btw when we open the access database file in the server it locks the file resulting which the clients cannot use that same file.

Comment: Its understandable that a college might teach and use tech that is somewhat behind the times but to use out-of-support tech like VB6 is inexcusable, esp in the light of freely available tools such as VB.NET and Java development environments.

Comment: I still maintain some software that uses VB6 and Access, but even I would advise using something more modern here. It's a new development and (no offense Ankan) it seems from the question that the developers don't have much experience with VB6 and Access. So why not learn something newer, with longer to go on the support lifetime? I believe Access databases are prone to corruption when used heavily in multiuser environments.

Comment: @MarkJ: your beliefs about corruption are incorrect, unless lots of stupid mistakes are being made (such as not splitting, and sharing a front end).